# add a jquery date picker to php list

Tags: php, jquery

I have a mysql database table which contains a error code, date and mail address.

My script below displays a basic list as per the screenshot,

[image: Script displays as follows]

I would like to be able to filter by date, I am hoping to use jquery date picker.

The idea being, only show entries where the date matches that in the jquery date picker.

The php code used to display the list:

```
    <?php

// Add  Logo
$image = "logo.png";
$width = 300;
$height = 280;
echo '<img src="'.$image.'" style=width:"' . $width . 'px;height:' . $height . 'px;">';

// Make a MySQL Connection
mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("pmta_reporting") or die(mysql_error());

// Get all the data from the "example" table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM address")
or die(mysql_error());

echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr> <th>Error</th> <th>Date</th> <th>Mail Address</th> </tr>";
// keeps getting the next row until there are no more to get
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
        // Print out the contents of each row into a table
        echo "<tr><td>";
        echo $row['code'];
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo $row['date'];
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo $row['address'];
        echo "</td></tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
// disconnect from the database

    mysql_close();
?>
```

The code I am using for the date picker is

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
    <script>
       $(function() {
          $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
       });
   </script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" /></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

How can I add the jquery date picker to the script so that when a user selects a date the results shown on the page only display the date selected by the user?

Comment: I notice you to use a class instead a an id for this kind of functionnality.
An id it's just use one times, a class you can use several times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok made some changes. I have created 2 files in the directory.

index.php  - this contains the date picker and a submit

file2.php - this contains the database query and tables.

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker(({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" }));
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="file2.php" method="post">
            <p>Date: <input type="text" name="datepicker" id="datepicker" /></p>
            <div id="displaycontent"> </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then file2.php looks like this:

```
<?php

// Make a MySQL Connection
mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("databasename") or die(mysql_error());
$newdate = $_POST['datepicker'];

// Get all the data from the "example" table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE date='$newdate'") or die(mysql_error());

echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr> <th>Error</th> <th>Date</th> <th>Mail Address</th> </tr>";
 // keeps getting the next row until there are no more to get
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
    // Print out the contents of each row into a table
    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo $row['code'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $row['date'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $row['address'];
    echo "</td></tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
 // disconnect from the database

 mysql_close();
?>
```

This allows me to filter by date.

Thanks everyone for your contributions

Answer (score 1):

On value change in datepicker field, reload url with GET variable `date`:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).change(function(){
   window.location.href = window.location.href + '?date=' + $(this).val();
})
```

in php, if get variable is suplied add a where statement to the query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM address"
if (isset( $_GET['date']) && ($date = $_GET['date'])){
  $query .= " WHERE date = '$date'";
}
$result = mysql_query($query)
```

NOTE! this wont protect against sql injection!

Answer (score 1):

This would be a bit complicated to write up, so forgive me for not writing an example, but I'll give you a good idea of how to do this. First of all, you should make a separate PHP file that returns only the table and takes a `POST` variable argument for the date that it uses to filter the results in the `SQL` query. Next, use `jQuery`'s `.change()` on the `input` field that is the datepicker to make an `$.ajax` call with `$('#datepicker').val()` set in the data argument to the `PHP` file that returns your data and load it into a specified `<div>`.

You can read more about `$.ajax` here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

Might not be very efficient, but you can do this.

```
$("#date").datepicker({"dateFormat": "yy-mm-dd"});

$("#date").change(function() {
    var date_from_date_picker = $(this).val();
    $('td.date').each(function() {
        if ($(this).text() != date_from_date_picker) {
            $(this).parent().hide();
        } else {
            $(this).parent().show();
        }
    });
});
```

Working demo at http://jsfiddle.net/djhPN/2/

Answer (score 1):

In your HTML:

```
<body>
  <form method="get" action="yourphpscript">
    <p>Date: <input type="text" name="date" id="datepicker" /></p>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
  </form>
</body>
```

In your PHP you can use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php), that way you can use prepared statements and parameterized queries that protect you against SQL-injection.

Check out this post for more information:
[Examples of PDO & mysqli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

You could also escape the bad sql with the function "mysql_real_escape_string($bad_variable)"

I'll just adjust the code of Joel Harkes to make it work against SQL-injection also:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM address"
if (isset( $_GET['date']) && ($date = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['date']))){
  $query .= " WHERE date = '$date'";
}
$result = mysql_query($query)
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use ajax to load the content like this.

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<script>
   $(function() {
      $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
   });

   jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $("#datepicker").change(function(){

    var new_date = $(this).val();

    jQuery.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "http://www.url.php",
      data: { date:new_date },
      success: function( data ) {
               $('#displaycontent').val(data);
                }
       });
    });
  });
</script>

</head>
<body>
  <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" /></p>
  <div id="displaycontent"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and ajax file is ex. url.php is like this.

```
// Add  Logo
$image = "logo.png";
$width = 300;
$height = 280;
echo '<img src="'.$image.'" style=width:"' . $width . 'px;height:' . $height . 'px;">';

// Make a MySQL Connection
mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("pmta_reporting") or die(mysql_error());

$newdate = $_REQUEST['date'];

// Get all the data from the "example" table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM address WHERE date=".$newdate) or die(mysql_error());

echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr> <th>Error</th> <th>Date</th> <th>Mail Address</th> </tr>";
 // keeps getting the next row until there are no more to get
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
    // Print out the contents of each row into a table
    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo $row['code'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $row['date'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $row['address'];
    echo "</td></tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
 // disconnect from the database

 mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Thank you, The only question is I have created 2 files. one with the date, and the other containing the table code. once i select a date, how do I get it to "submit" to display the tables?

Comment: @rezizter we call ajax so when we change the date, jquery .change event is fire and ajax is call and your data is update.

Comment: I think there might be something misconfiguration on my server, as when I select the date it does not move. Is it possible to add a submit button instead?

Comment: @rezizter check using firebug that this ajax file is call when you change the date.

Comment: @rezizter it also possible using submit button.